# Show only username instead of email address devise confirmation email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am using `devise` for authentication in Rails project . and on `signup` it sends an email . The recipient watches `'xyz@example.com'` in `From` tab of email account. i want to show only username of sender like `'MyAppName'` in `From` tab of email account when user receives email . How can i achieve that .

Answer (score 1):

In the file `config/initializers/devise.rb`, you can edit the attribute `config.mailer_send` to include the name. It would look something like this:

```
config.mailer_sender = 'Alex Santos <alex@website.com>'
```

Comment: i added it and devise stopped sending email- i means logs show that email is sent . but i don't receive that

Comment: You shouldn't need to add it, just change whatever value is there. What devise version are you using?

Comment: I've tested it with that version, and it seems to work fine. The issue might be somewhere else. Email sending software, or something else in the code. If you're testing locally, a good way to quickly see the result is using letter_opener gem.

Comment: replaced , still no success . fyi . i have my smtp configs in `development .rb`

Comment: What SMTP server are you using?

Comment: gmail - email were going well before doing this

Comment: Just to be clear, you're using your `@gmail.com` account (the same that you were using before), instead of `alex@website.com`?